# apache2 rotate access.log at (exactly) midnight

Tags: apache, logging, debian

I have search and tried, but have not been able to get the desired outcome.

I wish to have my apache2 access.log file rotate at exactly midnight, daily. So there is a new access.log file every day from 00:00 to 23:59.

At the moment, no matter what I try, it seems to 'do its own thing' and move onto a new access.log file whenever it wants to, certainly not at midnight.

I am also very confused with CustomLog, rotatelogs and logrotate.

Would someone kindly help with how to get the apache2 access.log to move to a new file at exactly midnight?

Things I have tried :

Modify `/etc/logrotate.conf` as follows

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
daily
```

I have tried adding `CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/logfile.%Y.%m.%d 86400" common` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but then apache gives out 404's after a `service apache2 restart`

I was hoping it wouldn't be this hard to achieve. I'm running apache2 on a Debian VM. Thank you.

UPDATE : Oops, I could have sworn I posted this on serverfault!

UPDATE : So I've got somewhere. I have added the following to the 000-default.conf file

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" test
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/test.log" test
```

And this produces a new separate file called test.log and is logging, but if I try and add anything with rotatelogs such as this line `CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -f /var/log/apache2/test.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" test`

Then Apache refuses to restart with this `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

So all I'm doing is writing a new log file with a different name, nothing really gained.

If I run rotatelogs at command line, it responds, so it is definitely installed.

Any ideas?